# Why won't grunt run my task?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm attempting to use the grunt-email-inliner module and for some reason it doesn't appear to be running. I'm new to grunt, what am I missing? I triple checked the docs.

Here is a link to the plugin:
https://github.com/yargalot/Email-Builder

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({

    emailBuilder: {
      test: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'web/src/vm-templates',
          src: ['*.html'],
          dest: 'web/src/result/',
          ext: '.vm',
        }]
      }
    },
    less: {
      development: {
        options: {
          //compress: true,
          //yuicompress: true,
          //optimization: 2
        },
        files: {
          // target.css file: source.less file
          "WebContent/css/styles.css": "less/styles.less"
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      styles: {
        files: ['less/**'], // which files to watch
        tasks: ['less'],
        options: {
          nospawn: true
        }
      }
    }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-email-builder');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'watch', 'emailBuilder']);

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not running because you're declaring `watch` before you declare `emailBuilder`. `watch` fires and starts polling for changes before the `emailbuilder` can ever get a chance to run. Quadruple check next time.

After reorder:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'emailBuilder', 'watch']); // correct
```

[image: correct]

Before reorder:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'watch', 'emailBuilder']); // Incorrect
```

[image: incorrect]

Also, you're defining a `default` task twice:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['less']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'watch', 'emailBuilder']);
```

Drop the first one.

Comment: Thanks Seth, that solved it. Hope you and the rest of the family are doing well.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `src: ['*.html']` to `src: ['**/*.html']`

Comment: That still did not result in the files being generated.